# Не работает branches в APEX 19.1

Tags: oracle-apex

Начал изучать APEX (19.1). Нужно сделать примерно следующее: диалоговое окно (страница 2) с выбором параметра и кнопки "Создать" и "Отмена". Нажатие "Создать" выполняет plsql-код и переходит на страницу 3.

Из документации понял что это можно сделать с помощью Branches. Создал бранч "After processing". Однако, происходит только отработка "Submit" и закрытие окна "Close dialog after submit". А вот "Go another page"не запускается и переход на страницу 3 не выполняется.

Может быть где-то ещё нужно указать этот бранч чтобы заработало?

[image: Структура Processing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже разобрался. Если есть branch, то видимо не нужно добавлять закрытие. Убрал "Close dialog after submit" и заработало.